# EF 6 slowness issue with bigger model

Tags: entity-framework

I am using EF 6 with DB first approach and I am facing slowness issue. My table count crosses 600. Any help in this regard will be helpful.

I have created a dataaccess class in order to get data using singleton approach. Any good link or article may help.

Let me share my data model approach

DataAcess.cs

```
public class DataAccess
{
    internal Model.Entities _ctx = null;
    private static DataAccess self = null;
    public object ModulePermission;

    private DataAccess()
    {
        var tmp = new ConnectionStringBuilder(Utility.GetConnectionString());
        _ctx = new Model.Entities(tmp.CaliberMatrixString);

        // temporarily dissabling the EF entity validation - it should be removed in the next code sync.
        _ctx.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
    }

    public static DataAccess Instance
    {
        get
        {
            var context = HttpContext.Current;
            if (context != null)
            {
                const string kApplicationSettings = "ApplicationObject";
                if (context != null && context.Items[kApplicationSettings] != null)
                {
                    var da = context.Items[kApplicationSettings] as DataAccess;
                    return da;
                }

                self = new DataAccess();
                context.Items[kApplicationSettings] = self;
            }
            else
            {
                self = new DataAccess();
            }
            return self;
        }
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        _ctx.SaveChanges();
    }

    internal Model.CaliberMatrixEntities Ctx { get { return _ctx; } }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (self != null)
        {
            //DataAccess.Instance.Dispose();
            const string kApplicationSettings = "ApplicationObject";
            var context = HttpContext.Current;
            if (context != null && context.Items[kApplicationSettings] != null)
                context.Items[kApplicationSettings] = null;
            _ctx.Dispose();
            _ctx = null;
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
            self = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What slowness are you faceing?

Comment: Start with [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/performance/pre-generated-views) and [this](https://www.fusonic.net/developers/2014/07/09/3-steps-for-fast-entity-framework-6-1-code-first-startup-performance/).

Answer (score 0):

600 tables is a significant system size. A couple of factors to consider would be to determine whether areas of the application/system can be isolated to utilize smaller DbContexts. (Search up on Bounded Contexts)  This is easier to set up using a DB-First approach where you configure EF to an existing schema rather than trying to let EF manage the schema & migrations.  Smaller context classes are faster to initialize.

Another consideration would be that I'd be wary of attempting to use a static context. This hints at having a DbContext longer-lived than it is needed. DbContexts do not "age" well, in that their in-built change tracking means that their memory usage increases, and performance decrease with the more entities they become aware of. Bounded contexts will help with the spin-up time of a DbContext meaning you can keep them short-lived.